# Middleware hangs

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have the following middleware that does nothing but call `next()`:

```
export default function (options) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    next()
  };
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
import mymiddleware from '../middlewares/mymiddleware';

router.post('/', mymiddleware, function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(200).send()
});
```

When I post to the route it just hangs. I would expect this to return just return a 200 OK (which it does if I remove `mymiddleware` from my route)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting a function that returns a middleware function when it is called.  You have to call that outer function to get the middleware function.  You are not calling it.

So, you're passing a function as middleware that just returns another function which is never called so thus it never calls `next()` and thus your route appears to just get stuck.

You can fix it in two ways.  First, you can change your export to just export a straight middleware function:

```
export default function (req, res, next) {
    next()
}
```

Or, secondly if you need to keep the nested architecture so you can pass it options when using it, you have to actually call it and pass the required options to it:

```
import mymiddleware from '../middlewares/mymiddleware';

router.post('/', mymiddleware(someOptions), function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(200).send()
});
```